# How to merge two generic objects and get full type-safe result?

Tags: typescript

I've created a function for my React Native app that takes a `StyleSheet.NamedStyles<T>` like object but each style also can have a optional *dark* object as well that is another style itself. the function returns a hook that merges the dark style into the base style if my app theme is dark and returns it (if it's light theme than only the base style is returned).

Here is the source with some mocked types just for example. how can i make this work if it's even possible?

```js
// Example:
const useStyles = dynamicStyleSheet({
    example: {
        height: 50,
        color: "white",
        dark: {
            color: "black",
            width: 50
        }
    }
})
// ts might say useStyles is a hook and cannot be called here. it doesn't matter, the type matters.
const styles = useStyles()
type color = typeof styles.example.color // should be "white" | "black". but it's string
type height = typeof styles.example.height // should be 50. but it's number
type width = typeof styles.example.width // should be 50 | undefined. but it's number | undefined

type ImageStyle = {
    height?: number
    width?: number
    objectFit?: "cover" | "contain" | "fill" | "scale-down"
}

type TextStyle = {
    fontSize?: number
    color?: string
    fontStyle?: "normal" | "italic"
    textAlign?: "auto" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify"
}

type ViewStyle = {
    height?: number
    width?: number
    borderStyle?: "solid" | "dotted" | "dashed"
}

type DynamicNamedStyles<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: (ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle) & {
        dark?: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle
    }
}

type MergedStyles<T extends DynamicNamedStyles<T>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Omit<T[P], "dark"> & (T[P]["dark"] extends infer D ? Partial<D> : object)
}

type OmitDark<T> = Omit<T, "dark">

type FinalStyles<T extends DynamicNamedStyles<T>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: OmitDark<MergedStyles<T>[P]>
}

export function dynamicStyleSheet<T extends DynamicNamedStyles<T> | DynamicNamedStyles<any>>(
    styles: T & DynamicNamedStyles<any>
) {
    return function useStyles() {
        const isDark = useIsDarkScheme()

        const lightStyles = objectMap(styles, ({ dark, ...style }) => ({
            ...style
        })) as FinalStyles<T>

        const darkStyles = objectMap(styles, ({ dark, ...style }) => ({
            ...style,
            ...(dark ?? {})
        })) as FinalStyles<T>

        return isDark ? darkStyles : lightStyles
    }
}

const useIsDarkScheme = () => true // mock

type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T }
export function objectMap<TValue, TResult>(
    obj: Dictionary<TValue>,
    valSelector: (val: TValue, obj: Dictionary<TValue>) => TResult,
    keySelector?: (key: string, obj: Dictionary<TValue>) => string,
    ctx?: Dictionary<TValue>
) {
    const ret = {} as Dictionary<TResult>
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        const retKey = keySelector ? keySelector.call(ctx ?? null, key, obj) : key
        const retVal = valSelector.call(ctx ?? null, obj[key], obj)
        ret[retKey] = retVal
    }
    return ret
}
```

Comment: @jcalz Yes this is what i wanted, thank you. if you have any suggestion for better implementation/type for other things in the code as well it would be a amazing.

Comment: I modified the type slightly to make it easier to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will concern myself only with the typings here; I assume your implementation's behavior at runtime is acceptable (or at least out of scope for the question as asked).  Let's give `dynamicStyleSheet()` the following call signature:

```
declare function dynamicStyleSheet<
    const T extends Record<keyof T, Style & { dark?: Style }>>(
        styles: T
    ): () => { [K in keyof T]:
        MergeStyle<T[K], T[K]["dark"] & object>
    }

type Style = ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle;
```

So the type of `styles` is the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, Style & { dark?: Style }>`, meaning that each property is of type `Style` with an optional `dark` property also of type `Style`.  This, I believe, captures your general intent for the input type.

Note that `T` is a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters), meaning that when you call `dynamicStyleSheet({⋯})`, the compiler will infer the type of the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) passed into it as narrowly as possible, similar to how it would if you called `dynamicStyleSheet({⋯} as const)` using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  So it will keep track of the exact [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the properties, such as `"white"` and `"black"` and not just `string`... which you said mattered for your use case.

The return type of `dynamicStyleSheet` is a function that returns the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof T]: MergeStyle<T[K], T[K]["dark"] & object>}`, where `T[K]["dark"] & object` is the "dark" style type ([intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `object` to make sure that any `undefined` from having `dark` be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) is removed, and any `unknown` from having `dark` be missing is replaced with `object`.

Each property will be transformed from `T[K]` to `MergeStyle<T[K], T[K]["dark"] & object>>`.  So now we need to define `MergeStyle<T, D>` so it behaves as you want.

---

Here is one way to do it:

```
type MergeStyle<T extends Style, D extends object> =
    { [K in Exclude<keyof T | keyof D, "dark">]:
        (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined) |
        (K extends keyof D ? D[K] : never)
    } & {};
```

This is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where we iterate over all the properties in `T` and all the properties in `D`, except for `"dark"`.  For each key `K`, if it is present in `T` we include it, otherwise we include `undefined` to allow for the fact that the dark style might not be used.  And, for each key `K`, if it is present in `D` we include it, otherwise we include `never` because we will never overwrite the property with `undefined`.

Oh and that `& {}` at the end is just to convince IntelliSense to show the expand `MergeStyle<X, Y>` into its full set of properties instead of just leaving it `MergeStyle<X, Y>`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const useStyles = dynamicStyleSheet({
    example: {
        height: 50,
        color: "white",
        dark: {
            color: "black",
            width: 50
        }
    },
    example2: {
        textAlign: "center",
        dark: {}
    },
    example3: {
        dark: {
            fontStyle: "italic"
        }
    },
    example4: {
        borderStyle: "solid"
    }
})
```

produces:

```
const styles = useStyles();
/*
const styles: {
    readonly example: {
        height: 50;
        width: 50 | undefined;
        color: "white" | "black";
    };
    readonly example2: {
        textAlign: "center";
    };
    readonly example3: {
        fontStyle: "italic" | undefined;
    };
    readonly example4: {
        borderStyle: "solid";
    };
}
*/
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtgQwOYQMqgDbQLxQN4BQUxUAFhAJZKnAD8AXFAHYCucARhAE5EkDuFACbBSDZm048SUAPbsAVhADGwAGIU6jAERKZAN25aoAHyg6ZTYAgpMjprQDMKGDHbMBnJQiwBaQTL5bAgBfAgJQSCgAFQgAD2B0ECwoXEJpBwsEigAvCDFWDm5eYl0MGS4xd2AuGyRiqAzLRKwxLSZyxFcTMw1vCiUteuA44ABBDComVoQWYBk3LSwHYAWa6hXunQhLQ035FiqKBxBB0PDwaAA1Cgg+Zpx8evIqGnyJIukBYVFGAsl69jlQTce6tdwyCaCBb+YDDKGbQQIdzkKEhMIRaD3FJQa63LGmGLxfGwRAoe4AbjCwKUGAQXGgDhYTBUFAsUEEICYCDg-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-hMBgICBapRGuRJ5E0DJlLaVJpAyd094QI+z6dRJAlMSxwwLMJCCiVow3ENB9TVbV9WNWpmktZxuljBMSBMIZxmGHNUALdIS0WCtdlYI5G2kY0CTJl5Vg+W4-WDYIR0nSQZ11Q1l0QKFN3SBFUUxVo4KQrNVaUqEhX5UAA)